# Removing consecutive repeating characters using regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Lets say that I have something like this:

```
. . . . First . . Second. . . . . Third . . .
```

The desired output is:

```
.First.Second.Third.
```

How can I achieve this by using regular expressions? I have in mind something like this:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\.+", ".", RegexOptions.Multiline).Trim();
```

Tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: I'm confused. `Regex.Replace("....First..Second.....Third...", @"\.+", ".", RegexOptions.Multiline).Trim()` yields `.First.Second.Third.` exactly as you require. Where's the problem?

Comment: Do you want to remove *dots* only?

Comment: Can you post an example surrounded with <pre></pre> tags (**without** 4 leading spaces) so it formats correctly please. There's been a lot of wasted time answering the wrong question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have spaces between the dots, like it appears you do in the question, try:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\. ]*\. *", ".", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

This will convert any string of dots and spaces including at least a single dot.

```
". . .First" => ".First"
" . . First" => ".First"
" ... First" => ".First"
".   .First" => ".First"
"     First" => "     First"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=(.))\1+", "");
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/ujhF5r)**.

---

**Update** *(based on question update)*:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"((\s)?(\S)(?(2)|\s))\1+\s?", "$3");
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/hDFtKw)**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using back references?

Depending on your regexp engine, something like this: `(.)(\1)+`

One character (if you want dots only, say so - but that should be obvious how to do), and then at least one more copy of this. Replace the string with `\1` - the results of the first group - and it should work. It definitely does for me with perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.)(\1)+/\1/g'
aaa bbb   ccc def abbc
a b c def abc
```

Any repeated character was replaced with the first occurrence only.

Answer (score 0):

As per your most recent (and hopefully correct) revision:

```
Regex.Replace(
   ". . . . First. . . Second. . . . . . Third. . .", 
   @"(?: *\. *)+", 
   ".", 
   RegexOptions.Multiline)
.Trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one also:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "[. ]+(?=[^ .])?",".");
```

This pattern will look for characters "." and " " unless it is followed by some character other than these two.